# Firebase Download Url

Tags: java, android, firebase, uri, firebase-storage

I am trying to get image uri stored in my Firebase database but it always going in `onFailure` method. The Uri data in `onSucess` method is always null. I have tried all the solutions but didn't worked any.

```
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authenticationfailed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {

                                    onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }

    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
        String username = usernameFromEmail(user.getEmail());
             if(result != null) {
                  firebase_Storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile").child(user.getUid());
                 Bitmap bitmap = null;
                 try {
                     bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(),result);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,20,byteArrayOutputStream);
                 byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                 UploadTask uploadTask = firebase_Storage.putBytes(data);


                 uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                         Log.e("InsideOnSuccess",taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                         uri_data = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                     }
                 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                          Log.e("Failed","Failed");
                     }
                 });
                 writeNewUser(name,user.getUid(), user.getEmail());
             }
```

The main task is to get the URI and save into Firebase database. But i ma having this problem while doing it. Any suggestions how can i do it?

Edit : - I am having this exception message in onFailure method : "Object does not exist at location."

Comment: Are you getting the image from your phone(local file)?

Comment: I have the image in my firebase storage console.

Comment: Log the actual Exception object.  What does it say?  `Log.e(TAG, "Failed", e);`

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson it is not even coming in onFailure now and profile link is not getting save in firebase database

Comment: You say "it always going in onFailure method". What is the Exception message?

Comment: Please post the structure you see in your Firebase Storage Console